# Selecting a column value based on the value from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas dataframe` similar to the one below:

```
  |   Date  | Value1 | Value2
0 | 2021-01 | 10.90  | 2.34
1 | 2021-02 | 12.85  | 4.65
2 | 2021-03 | 15.56  | 6.11
3 | 2021-04 | 18.23  | 8.62
```

Sample Code to create dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ['2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04'],
    "Value1": [10.90, 12.85, 15.56, 18.23],
    "Value2": [2.34, 4.65, 6.11, 8.62]
})
```

I want to extract the value from the `Value1` and `Value2` columns using a specific `Date` without making `Date` as index of the `dataframe`.

What I have done, works fine but looking for some better approach.

**Single line code** will be much appreciated for this task.

My approach:

```
value1_2021_01 = df[df["Date"] == '2021-01'][['Value1']].iat[0,0]

value2_2021_04 = df[df["Date"] == '2021-04'][['Value2']].iat[0,0]
```

Please note that the `Date` columns will always have unique values.

Comment: `df.loc[df["Date"].isin(['2021-01', '2021-04']), ['Value1', 'Value2']]` ?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan For single values, the return type is a `pandas.DataFrame` .. I need the `float` value. Adding `.iat[0,0]` at the end does the job but it more or less comes down to the same solution as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
value1_2021_01 = df.loc[list(df["Date"]).index("2021-01"), "Value1"]
values = df.loc[list(df["Date"]).index("2021-01"), ["Value1", "Value2"]]  # for both values
```

On my machine it required 1/50 of the execution time for *value1_2021_01 = df[df["Date"] == '2021-01'][['Value1']].iat[0,0]*.

Comment: I like the `.index()` part you used but how about when we have a large sample size ? Also, it does not work in my case, since the `Date` column is a `Timestamp` field.

Comment: The performance gain decreases. However, with 10e3 rows, it still took only half the time compared to _df[df["Date"] == '2021-01'][['Value1']].iat[0,0]_. I guess, you could either cast the timestamps to strings or specify the index value as a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the question correctly but do you want something like this:

```
g = lambda x: df.query(f'Date=="{x}"')[['Value1', 'Value2']]
value1,value2 = g('2021-01').values[0]
```

---

```
print(value1, value2)
```

---

**output:**

```
(10.9, 2.34)
```

Comment: Did not think about using `query` because it is slower in operations (if I am not wrong) . But thanks, this adds some information  !

Comment: Yes you can use `df[col].eq(...)` also